# Python C# interop

Tags: c#, interop, ironpython

In an assembly Test.Dll I have a C# class:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  int _TheInt;

  public MyClass (int i) {_TheInt = i;}
  public int GetInt() { return _TheInt;}
}
```

and a function:

```
public int MyFunc(MyClass myObject) { return myObject.GetInt(); }
```

How, in an ironPython script, create an object of type MyClass and call MyFunc with this object?
I can do the first step but as I am not an expert in neither C# and Python I failed for the second step.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import dll:

```python
import clr    
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"/path/to/Test.dll")
```

then after reference was added, you can import your C# namespace or class, and create the object:

```python
import MyNameSpace.MyClass # namespace name class from C# DLL

obj = MyClass(1)

# Now you have an object, let's call the methods:
myIntValue = obj.GetInt()
```

Then, if you want to call MyFunc, instead of direct call of GetInt(), you need to make it static (since it accepts object as argument

```csharp
//Put that inside MyClass declaration, cause global functions are not allowed by C#
public static int MyFunc(MyClass myObject) { return myObject.GetInt(); }
```

And call it on python's side:

```python
result = MyClass.MyFunc(obj)
```